# How to find the exact zoom position in Open street Map?

Tags: c#, maps, openstreetmap

I am using Open street map. In that, i want zoom a particular location. I am getting the corresponding zoom point from the Touch event of a Frame layout, where the tiles are arranged.My question is how to convert this pixel value to latitude and longitude value. I have referred below link for the latitude and longitude conversion.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb259689.aspx

Comment: Which library/framework/tool is your question about?

Comment: i am developing an app in xamarin android

Answer (score 0):

See [slippy map tilenames](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_map_tilenames) in the OSM wiki.

It explains how tile names work. It also contains a formula for converting tile numbers to lat/lon (and vice versa) and implementations for these formulas in various programming languages, including [C#](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_map_tilenames#C.23).

Comment: My requirement, I am getting pixel value (screen co-ordinate), and also the OSM tile is scaled at this point. From this need to find the exact zoom position and convert it to latitude and longitude value. With this I need to load the new zoomed region of map

Comment: You need to know the tile numbers (X and Y) and zoom level in order to calculate lat and lon. Then put these numbers into the formular from the wiki to obtain lat and lon of the top left edge of your tile.

Comment: I getting screen co-ordinate pixel value. if i substitute value to this formula, wrong tile is rendering?

Comment: The pixels are worth nothing if you don't know the tile numbers and zoom level. Also until now you never mentioned xamarin before. That's why I asked for the framework you are using. I have no experience with xamarin.

Comment: Could tell me, how to achieve this using c#?